# createWriteStream and createReadStream not working properly with Socket

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
let filesend = fs.createReadStream('./flex1.zip', 'utf8')
//let filesend = fs.createReadStream('./flex1.zip')
let fileget = fs.createWriteStream('./test/flex1.zip', 'utf8')
//let fileget = fs.createWriteStream('./test/flex1.zip')
fileget.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('getover')
})

net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.pipe(fileget)
    socket.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    });
}).listen('18800', function() {
    console.log('server_open')
});


let client = new net.Socket();
client.connect('18800', '127.0.0.1', function() {
    filesend.pipe(client);
});
```

when I call CreateReadStream and createWriteStream and set the encoding with 'utf8', I couldn't get the proper file,however if I didn't set the encoding ,I can get proper file.
All above situations happened while only using Socket

Comment: what is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

If `createReadStream` and `createWriteStream` work fine for you with `utf8`, then it makes no difference weather you use socket or http.

The problem is only with your content to be read/written, what you are changing in case of socket. I can see `filesend.pipe(client);`

If you can console/print your `client` and can see it is what you want then just write it without `utf8` because you do not need. Also if your client object is fine =>(its properties have no infinite recursion), an encoding like `utf8` would have no problem as well